# I need help tidying data for topic modelling

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R but I am having a problem with part of text pre-processing and cleaning before topic modelling. I am trying to Tokenise text to turn each document into a list of words- punctuation is removed as part of this process - column is called text

```
tokens <- text_input %>% unnest_tokens(words, text)
```

but I keep getting the error message

```
Error in UseMethod("unnest_tokens_") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

My text data is currently

```
text     <chr> "mr smiths tenant called for support "
...
```

I need each document to be turned into a list of words so spell checking etc can be completed and then topic modelling

**Code already tried**
Basic dataframe called `input` and then `text_input`
Database: spark_connection

```
$ lines    <chr> "  mr smiths tenant called for support    "

# set the name of the column with your source text

text_col <- "lines"

## Basic cleaning

text_input <- input %>%   
 filter(!is.na(!!as.name(text_col))) %>%  
 mutate(text = trimws(!!as.name(text_col)))%>%
 mutate(text = tolower(text))

## Tokenise Text
## Turns each document into a list of words; punctuation is removed as part of this process

tokens <- text_input %>% unnest_tokens(words, text)

Error in UseMethod("unnest_tokens_") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

Comment: Hello, Can you please share the whole code, please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: try `tokens <- text_input %>% unnest_tokens(word, text, token = "text_input")`

Comment: this is what I get  Basic Df called input  and then text_input 
Database: spark_connection
$ lines    <chr> "  mr smiths tenant called for support                                                                   
$ text     <chr> "mr smiths tenant called for support 


# set the name of the column with your source text

text_col <- "lines"

## Basic cleaning

```{r}
text_input <- input %>% 
  
filter(!is.na(!!as.name(text_col))) %>%
  
mutate(text = trimws(!!as.name(text_col)))%>%
  
mutate(text = tolower(text))

Comment: ctd   
## Tokenise Text
Turns each document into a list of words- punctuation is removed as part of this process
```{r}
tokens <- text_input %>% unnest_tokens(words, text)
```

Comment: It's much easier to follow your code if you [edit] the question instead of putting it unformatted in comments